Set highest CPU and IO priority for a systemd service
How to set CPU and IO priority for a systemd service? In partucular, how to set the highest values?
(Assume that the service is idling most of the time and will absolutely NOT clog the rest of the system. Assume that the request is intentional and desired.)

You need to set 3 things: CPU scheduling and its priority, IO scheduler and niceness.
To make your service use the highest values for all of these:
[Unit]
...

[Service]
CPUSchedulingPolicy=rr
CPUSchedulingPriority=99
IOSchedulingClass=realtime
Nice=-20
...

This is approximately the same as if you'd run the executable with:
sudo chrt -r 99 -- nice -n -20 -- ionice -c realtime -- my_process my_arguments

In htop, you'll see the process as:
PRI    IO     NI
----------------
 RT    R4    -20

